# Display input fields with style as display:none' not working

Tags: jquery, html-table, show-hide

I have a table with a `'+'` button within the last `<td>` of each row.

```
<input value="+" class="more-290-0 more_button" type="button">
```

On clicking that button,the same row will be inserted immediately after the clicked row with `'+' button` for add  and `'X' button` for remove the current row.After clicking '+' button ,the `'+' button` will be hidden.

When The `'X'` button is clicked,the current row will be hidden and the elements inside the last  of the immediate previous row before should be displayed.

My function for remove button is as follows.The current row is removing but the last hidden elements inside last `<td>` of previous row is not showing.
I have put alert for getting the `<td>` elements ,but I am not able to show the hidden elements

```
$(document).on ('click','.remove',function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').hide();
  if($(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').hasClass
     ($(this).closest('tr').prop('class')))
  {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td:eq(4)').html());
    //$(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td:eq(4)').children(':hidden').show();
    //this is not working
  }
});
```

My fiddle:[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anazvak/r3qhokqn/1/)

Comment: @freedomn-m I am not having any field with `<input type="hidden"/>`.I am just hiding on button click.

Comment: @freedomn-m I need to show a button which is having style as display:none

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I misread `.children(':hidden')`

Comment: Maybe if you included some html...

Comment: Without knowing the html structure - maybe change `.children(":hidden")` to `.find(":hidden")`

Comment: @freedomn-m I have created a fiddle .Maybe you can check plz.

Comment: @freedomn-m https://jsfiddle.net/anazvak/r3qhokqn/1/

Comment: Ok, had a quick look and, if I uncomment the code, clicking the [x] on the last row unhides the button just fine.  Sure it now has [x] in because you change the caption elsewhere, but the un-hide/show works fine.

Comment: @freedomn-m lemme check how that happens

Comment: @freedomn-m Now I have solved the issue.I need to check one thing more,if remove button is clicked,I need to check no other rows with the same classname should have remove button and plus button as displayed,if so,only hide the current row